# How to save n values from n forms in a database

Tags: php, mysql

I need to develop a script wich will do the following steps:

1.Users enters on a page named  update.php

There will be an input like this:

```
 How many values do you want to add ?: <input type="text" value="5">
```

2.At the moment when users clicks Submit and chooses, for example 5 values to be added, it will be redirected to page like this:

```
update.php?values=5
```

From that part i don't know how to make this:

3.The page should output 5 fields, or 20, or 3 (it depends on how many the user will choose)
and a submit button.

Example:

```
 <form action"x.php> 
<input type="text" name="value1" >
 <input type="text" name="value2" >
 <input type="text" name="value3" >
 <input type="text" name="value4" >
 <input type="text" name="value5" >
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add">
</form>
```

4.When all forms are completed and submited, i need to insert each value in a MYSQL database...

```
Table: values
id   value
1       x
2       y
3       z
4       a
5       b
```

I have made step 1 and 2 with issets...but i can't do the 3 and 4. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you going in the right direction, and is assuming that you don't actually need to name the fields explicitly `value1`, `value2`, etc.

**update.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["values"]))
{
?>
<form action="x.php"> 
<?php
    for($i = 0; $i < $_GET["values"]; $i++)
    {
        <input type="text" name="values[]" >
    }
?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add">
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

**x.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["values"]))
{
    foreach($_GET["values"] as $value)
    {
        $value = someSanitizationMethod($value);

        // YOUR CODE TO INSERT $value INTO THE DATABASE
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: it works, but if i have 2 sets of values ?  <br>                                        `if(isset($_POST["values"]) && isset($_POST["secondvalues"]) )
{
    foreach($_POST["values"] as $value && $_POST["secondvalues"] as $secondvalue)
    {
        //$value = someSanitizationMethod($value);

        // YOUR CODE TO INSERT $value INTO THE DATABASE
  
  $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO test_a VALUES('', $secondvalue, $value)") or die(mysql_error());} } `   <br> this won't work

Answer (score 0):

Here's number 3 for update.php.

```
if (isset($_GET['values'])){
    $numvalues = $_GET['values'];
}
for ($i=0;$i<$numvalues;$i++){
    echo '<input type="text" name="value'.$i.'" >';
}
```

For number 4, there are a semi-infinite number of answers on SO about how to insert data into MySQL database. I can tell you that you will have to change this line since it's broken:

```
<form action"x.php>
```

It will change to something like this if the form posts to itself for processing:

```
<form method="post">
```

Or this if it posts to a different processing page:

```
<form action="x.php" method="post">
```